# How to add, edit, view, and delete options in the table last columns using swimlane ngx datatable

Tags: angular8, angular9, angular10, angular11

I am trying to add/show edit and delete and view options for a status column in the table but not able to do that. Because table data is coming from JSON. So How to add those and resolve this issue? Help me to find the solution.

app.component.html:

```
<ngx-datatable
    style="width: 90%"
    class="material"
    [rows]="rows"
    [columns]="columns"
    [columnMode]="'force'"
    [headerHeight]="50"
    [footerHeight]="50"
    [rowHeight]="'auto'"
    [limit]="5"
    [selected]="selected"
    [selectionType]="'checkbox'"
    [selectAllRowsOnPage]="false"
    (select)='onSelect($event)'>
</ngx-datatable>
```

Demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ngx-datatable-select-checkbox-xxfvnx?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts